# Difference between the absolute maximum and minimum of $f(x)=2x^3–9x^2+12x+5$

Tags: calculus

> Let $M$ and $m$ be respectively the absolute maximum and the absolute minimum value of the function, $f(x)=2x^3–9x^2+12x+5$ in the interval $[0,3]$. Then $M–m$ is equal to:

The derivative is $(x-1)(x-2)$ local minimum at 2 is 9 and the local maximum at 1 is 10.However the question asks for the difference between the **global** maximum and minimum. So I checked the function at 0 and 3 as well which yield 5 and 14 respectively. Using the first set of points at local maximum gives me the answer as 1 but using the latter set of points give me a 9.

This was a question asked in the Joint Engineering Examination thus so far i haven't been able to obtain an official answer key.

Some sites suggest that the answer is 1 while others suggest it as 9. I vaguely recall being taught that if an interval is open then we do not consider the maxima/minima at the end points of an interval but over here the interval is closed so this shouldn't impose a problem. 9 is the correct answer, am I right?

Comment: English hint:  maxima and minima are plural.  The singulars are maximum and minimum.

Comment: I think nine is the correct answer since the interval is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is good.  You compare the values at the critical points and the endpoints to find the global maximum, which here is $14$.  You do the same to find the global minimum, which is $5$.  The difference is $9$.

If the interval were open at both ends it would not attain $5$ or $14$ but would get as close as you want.  There would not be a global maximum or minimum in that case and the question would not have an answer.

Comment: This not true, sorry. It is $$14-5=9$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner:  are you referring to the second paragraph?  With an open interval there is not $x$ with $f(x)=14$, nor one with $f(x)=5$.  The sup of the difference in function values is $9$, but there is no maximum difference in function values.  Maxima must be attained.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a figure is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The critical values are the roots of $\;f'(x)=6x^2-18x+12=6(x-1)(x-2)$. Furthermore, as the leading coefficient of this cubic polynomial is positive, a *local* maximum is first attained at $1$, and a *local* minimum at $2$.

So the global maximum on $[0,3]$ is attained  either at $1$ or at $3$. Similarly the global minimum on $[0,3]$ is attained either at $2$ or $0$. To find them we only have to compute the values of $f(x)$ at these points:
$$\begin{array}{r!{}cccc}
x=&0&1&2&3 \\
\hline
f(x)=&5&10&9&10
\end{array}$$
We see the global maximum is $M=10$ and the global minimum is $m=5$, so
$$M-m=5.*$$